# Create a webbrowser in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, browser

Is it possible to create a webbrowser inside a Flex (not AIR!) application?
I want to display some links in a Flex application and when a user clicks the links, it should open a custom component with some sort of a webbrowsing component. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, everything is possible, but why?

Comment: Well. We create a Projector (.exe) from our Flex application, which will be launched fullscreen. We want to show a webpage when a user clicks a link inside the application; because it otherwise would open an external webbrowser, which minimizes our application. That's why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm
has a great example

if that doesn't work for you, look at this:
http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/

Comment: This is great, thanks. Can't believe this has been around so long.

Comment: Indeed this is really great! Just what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no. There are some simple html rendering capabilities built-in but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Long answer - it's possible inside browser, eg. using IFrame, or using AIR, which has a built in broswer. If having an exe file and not an AIR file is a problem, AIR 2.0 allows you to create native application installers. Check it at [Adobe labs](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/).

Comment: The problem is, we want our application to run without any installation (like running from a usb stick). What html rendering capabilities are you refering to?

Comment: Hardly any, you can try setting the htmlText field of some components, check this article: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html , it's nowhere near "web-browsing"